# Find an entry in sql dependent on other entries in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I return all entries in a table that contain a string in a given column if the same string is also present in the same column with a given suffix ?

So for example, given the suffix 'bar', and the following table:

```
id A
1 foo1
2 foo2
3 foo1bar
```

I want to return the the first entry, because there's another entry (the third one) which has the same value when the suffix is appended.

Comment: Did you give this a try, show us what you have so far

Comment: Do a self join, or use EXISTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON CONCAT(t1.column, 'bar') = t2.column
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.a = concat(t.a, 'bar')
             );
```

I recommend this specifically over a `join` to avoid returning duplicate values, in the event that multiple rows match the conditions.